# How can I omit case sensitivity for this parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have created a discord help command that loops through the bot's cogs and displays the categories in a list. I have also made it so that the user can input a category so they can get a list of commands from said category. I'm stuck trying to omit case sensitivity for the parameter when comparing the input and the list of classes. Any help is appreciated!

```
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def help(self, ctx, *cog : str):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        data = await self.bot.prefixes.get_by_id(ctx.message.guild.id)
        if not data or "prefix" not in data:
            prefix = "."
        else:
            prefix = data["prefix"]

        if cog:  # If Cogs Are Specified
            Exists = False  # Default

            for a in self.bot.cogs:
                for b in cog:

                    if a == b:
                        print(a + "- Cog")
                        print(b + "- Input")
                        print()
                        help = discord.Embed(color=7799039)
                        help.title = f'Commands:'
                        help.description = self.bot.cogs[cog[0]].__doc__

                        for command in self.bot.get_cog(a).get_commands():
                            if not command.hidden:
                                help.add_field(
                                    name=f"{prefix}{command.name}", value=command.help, inline=False)
                        Exists = True
```

Comment: Please only ask questions with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It takes too long to find the code-line, which actually does the comparing.

Comment: take a look at the str.lower() function for a hint

Comment: @itzFlubby i have edited the question to only show the part where it compares the input and the class. Any ideas?

Comment: @itprorh66 told you the answer.  Did you read it?  `if a.lower() == b.lower():`